# telegram bot on heroku doesn't work with webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

My telegram bot doesn't work in production mode. It fails to respond to the commands /start and /echo; Heroku logs also remain silent. The only working feature is the purchase of goods, which is processed in app.post (**bot.answerWebAppQuery**). Most likely, the issue lies in app.port, as in the development mode that employs polling instead of a webhook, everything works fine, except for **bot.answerWebAppQuery**, of course.

All this can be seen visually in the telegram: **@ReactWebAppBot**

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/1KiritoS1/tg-web-app-bot)

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const bot = require('./bot');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/web-data', async (req, res) => {
    const { queryId, products, totalPrice } = req.body;

    try {
        await bot.answerWebAppQuery(queryId, {
            type: 'article',
            id: queryId,
            title: 'Успешна покупка!',
            input_message_content: {
                message_text: `Поздравляю с покупкой, вы приобрели товар на сумму $${totalPrice}
                "${products.map(item => item.title).join(', ')}"`
            }
        });
        bot.processUpdate(req.body);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Ok' });
    } catch (e) {
        await bot.answerWebAppQuery(queryId, {
            type: 'article',
            id: queryId,
            title: 'Не удалось приобрести товар :(',
            input_message_content: { 
                message_text: 'Не удалось приобрести товар :(' 
            }
        });
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error' });
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server started on PORT ' + PORT));
```

**bot.js**

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
require('dotenv').config();

const token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
const webAppUrl = 'https://tg-webapp-react.netlify.app';

let bot;
  
const initPolling = () => {
    bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });
    
    console.log('Bot started in the dev mode with polling.');
}

const initWebhook = () => {
    bot = new TelegramBot(token);

    const webhookUrl = process.env.HEROKU_URL + bot.token;
    console.log('Webhook URL:', webhookUrl);
    bot.setWebHook(webhookUrl);

    console.log('Bot started in the prod mode with webhook.');
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    initWebhook();
} else {
    initPolling();
}

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    const text = msg.text;
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;

    if (text === '/start') {
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Заполни форму', {
            reply_markup: {
                keyboard: [
                    [{ text: 'Заполнить форму', web_app: { url: webAppUrl + '/form' } }]
                ]
            }
        });
        await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Заходи сюда', {
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: [
                    [{ text: 'Сделать заказ', web_app: { url: webAppUrl } }]
                ]
            }
        });
    }
    if (msg.web_app_data?.data) {
        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(msg.web_app_data?.data);

            await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Спасибо за обратную связь!');
            await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Ваша страна: ' + data?.country);
            await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Ваша улица: ' + data?.street);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
});

module.exports = bot;
```

**Heroku logs:**

```
2023-12-25T14:55:09.324439+00:00 app[web.1]: > tg-web-app-bot@1.0.0 start
2023-12-25T14:55:09.324439+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2023-12-25T14:55:09.324439+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-12-25T14:55:09.600098+00:00 app[web.1]: Webhook URL: https://<app-name>.herokuapp.com/<bot-token>
2023-12-25T14:55:09.604960+00:00 app[web.1]: Bot started in the prod mode with webhook.
2023-12-25T14:55:09.608718+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on PORT 11228
2023-12-25T14:55:10.054273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-12-25T14:55:43.228297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/6712623296:AAHGTjFF0m9TgkFLwe7vtke-Q2MQJ57xdUo" host=web-app-bot-fbadb4b5a054.herokuapp.com request_id=b778f8aa-6af0-4078-b6fd-fe702ea37a63 fwd="91.108.6.73" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=462 protocol=https
```